# How to trace where Xcode program crash

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

I'm getting an error in debugger. In Thread my app crash on line:

```
0x37265f78:  ldr    r3, [r4, #8]
```

with:

```
Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x50000008)
```

How to find out where app actually crash? There is a something like "call stack"?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You have to set `Exception Breakpoint` 
Go to the Breakpoints navigator, click the + button at the bottom, and add an Exception Breakpoint.
Now you will know the exact line where any of your exception will occur (e.g. line of crash). best of luck!!

Comment: All this d@mn time I've been wondering why it doesn't tell you where your app fails. Thank you, sincerely.

Answer (score 5):

http://www.raywenderlich.com/10209/my-app-crashed-now-what-part-1

Best tutorial for trace the error.

Answer (score 2):

Run your app under the debugger, then when your app crashes you will have access to the call stack.

Furthermore, if you display the console window, you will get more textual information (including a call stack) at the moment of the crash.

If you are using Xcode 4, have a look at the attached picture.[image]