# Trying to trace an error in xcode

Tags: objective-c

When I start up my application I get the error detailed below. If I continue the application everything seems to be working fine. The error is raised between the calls to applicationWillFinishLaunching and applicationDidFinishLaunching.

I suspect the eror is getting generated when the xib is being loaded, however I can see nothing wrong with the xib and how it is connected up. Can anyone give me some tips on how I can trace back to find the source of the error?

Thanks,

```
2012-08-21 11:31:55.293 ConjugationViewer[32508:707] *** Assertion failure in -[NSTextFieldCell _objectValue:forString:errorDescription:], /SourceCache/AppKit/AppKit-1138.47/AppKit.subproj/NSCell.m:1564
2012-08-21 11:31:55.303 ConjugationViewer[32508:707] Ignoring exception raised in __-[NSPersistentUIManager restoreAllPersistentStateWithTalagentWindows:registeringAsReadyWhenDone:completionHandler:]_block_invoke_3: Invalid parameter not satisfying: aString != nil
```

Comment: Search your code for `aString != nil` and post the code around it.

Comment: Nowhere in my code is there aString != nil. I'm assuming that somewhere in a library there is an assert to this effect, probably in [NSPersistentUIManager restoreAllPersistentStateWithTalagentWindows:registeringAsReadyWhenDone:completionHandler:]. But presumably this is getting called based on some information in my xib. So I think I need to trace back to which piece of my xib it's looking at when it gets this error?

Comment: Success! I found this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10878035/how-to-trace-where-xcode-program-crash?rq=1 which explains how to set an exception breakpoint, once I understood that, it was easy.

Comment: Don't forget to post your solution as an answer when SO allows you to.

Answer (score 2):

I had same problem.

In my case I had set

`[NSTextField setStringValue:nil]` By mistake.

You can trace the problem in your code using **crash stack log**.

The log shows function call as stack start from bottom. You can search the last call of your function after which cocoa functions get called. You can say problem present at the same function.

Comment: Isn't this kinda obvious?