# NSInvalidArgumentException Invalid type in Json write objective c

Tags: ios, json, objective-c

I am new to objective c. I get NSInvalidArgumentException Invalid type in Json write (NSError) at the following line.

```
  NSURLSessionDataTask *result = [self POST:@"/analytics"
                                  parameters:params completion:^(OVCResponse * _Nullable response, NSError * _Nullable error) {
                                      [self handleResponse:response error:error adjustErrorBlock:self.commonErrorAdjustBlock completion:theCompletion];
                                  }];
```

The code is the following

```
 NSArray *params = [MTLJSONAdapter JSONArrayFromModels:events error:NULL];
        
    void(^theCompletion)(id _Nullable, NSError * _Nullable) = ^(id _Nullable result, NSError * _Nullable error) {
        completion(error);
    };
    
    NSURLSessionDataTask *result = [self POST:@"/analytics/"
                                   parameters:params completion:^(OVCResponse * _Nullable response, NSError * _Nullable error) {
                                       [self handleResponse:response error:error adjustErrorBlock:self.commonErrorAdjustBlock completion:theCompletion];
                                   }];
```

handleresponse method

```
- (void)handleResponse:(nullable OVCResponse *)response error:(nullable NSError *)error adjustErrorBlock:(nullable C8ApiClientv2AdjustErrorBlock)adjustErrorBlock completion:(void (^)(id _Nullable result, NSError * _Nullable error))completion {
    
    DebugLog(@"\n===[start response] <%@> \n===%@, \nerror:%@\n===[end response] <%@> ", self.class, response, error, self.class);
    
        NSError *adjustedError = nil;
        if (NULL != adjustErrorBlock){
            adjustedError = adjustErrorBlock(error, response);
        }
        
        if (nil != adjustedError) {
            completion(nil, adjustedError);
        } else {
            if (response.HTTPResponse.statusCode >= 200 && response.HTTPResponse.statusCode <= 299) {
                NSAssert(error == nil, @"got error though request succeded");
            }
            else if (response.HTTPResponse.statusCode == 401) {
                error = NSError.com_eight_APIServiceUnauthorizedError;
            }
            else if (response.HTTPResponse.statusCode >= 500 && response.HTTPResponse.statusCode <= 599) {
                error = nil != error ? error : NSError.com_eight_APIServiceUnknownError;
                [SentrySDK captureMessage:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Request failed: internal server error (500):\n%@", response]];
            }
            else {
                error = nil != error ? error : NSError.com_eight_APIServiceUnknownError;
            }
            
            id result = nil == error ? response.result : nil;
            completion(result, error);
        }
    
}
```

Trace

```
-[AFJSONRequestSerializer requestBySerializingRequest:withParameters:error:]
(AFNetworking/AFNetworking/AFURLRequestSerialization.m:1312)
8
+0x01f480
-[AFHTTPRequestSerializer requestWithMethod:URLString:parameters:error:]
(AFNetworking/AFNetworking/AFURLRequestSerialization.m:407)
8
+0x161de8
-[OVCHTTPSessionManager _dataTaskWithHTTPMethod:URLString:parameters:completion:]
(Overcoat/sources/Core/OVCHTTPSessionManager.m:74)
8
+0x1621f0
-[OVCHTTPSessionManager POST:parameters:completion:]
(Overcoat/sources/Core/OVCHTTPSessionManager.m:129)
8
+0x42d98c
-[C8AnalyticsClientv2 trackEvents:completion:]
(DAL/Networkingv2/Clients/C8AnalyticsClientv2.m:40)
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Where is called `NSJSONSerialization` in your code? Inside `JSONArrayFromModels`? What's that method? What's `POST:parameters:completion:`? There is hidden code which causes the issue, so we can't really help you here.

Comment: what is the NSJSONSerialization? The error occurs in completion as i understand.

Comment: It's a class. When I see the error you got "invalid type in JSON write", I suspects it's called somewhere... Define exactly which line is causing the crash. But show the code of the method that causes the crash, not just the call.

Comment: You mean handleresponse method?

Comment: I guess. But don't you have a stacktrace? More infos in Console ? See https://stackoverflow.com/a/10878155/1801544 there should be more info above "invalid JSON write", where we should be able to see which part was the last called.

Comment: I added handleresponse.

Comment: I am thinking that i have to add something like this in handleresponse     if ([error isKindOfClass:[NSError class]]) {
to check if error passed is actually an NSError class object...but i do not know if i am right.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238428/discussion-between-larme-and-stefanosn).